# Will JWST be handed over from Arianespace/ESA/CNES to NASA at some point the way Cape Canaveral handed over missions to Houston?

Tags: nasa, esa, james-webb-telescope, flight-control, mission-control

Will JWST be handed over from Arianespace/ESA/CNES to NASA at some point the way Cape Canaveral handed over missions to Houston?

JWST has its own propulsion and communication system. Presumably the propulsion can't be used until the second stage disengages, but is that when NASA can start sending commands?

Before that can they send any commands through Arianespace/ESA/CNES?

Or do they just listen?

Related: Phys.org's [ESA to pick up as Webb phones home](https://phys.org/news/2021-12-esa-webb-home.html)

From Spaceflight Now's [Europe’s spaceport, flagship launcher ready for historic Webb mission](https://spaceflightnow.com/2021/12/24/europes-spaceport-flagship-launcher-ready-for-historic-webb-mission/):

> The rocket’s French-made core stage will perform roll maneuvers to keep the observatory in thermal balance, ensuring parts of the telescope don’t get too hot or too cold. Webb’s control team at the Space Telescope Science Institute in Baltimore, Maryland, expects to receive the first signals from the spacecraft as soon as the fairing separates from the rocket.

Comment: Note: one of the delays last week was because of a communication issue between Ariane and JWST. So, at least, the *vehicles* can talk to each other, which makes it likely that the JWST control could talk to JWST through Ariane if they wanted to.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes good point! The first info from the telescope post launch will likely be via the 2nd stage to ESA's Malindi Ground Station (1st link). In the Northrop Grumman video [James Webb Space Telescope Launch and Deployment](https://youtu.be/v6ihVeEoUdo?t=310) it shows the telescope's own high gain antenna deploying somewhere around 15 to 20 hours after launch (hard to tell) whereas 2nd stage separation is only at 30 minutes or so. I haven't had time to check the actual launch yet (still waiting for morning coffee to kick in) but hopefully that high gain antenna will be deployed soon.

Comment: Oh, at `T+00:20:07` (`01:52:19` in [this video](https://youtu.be/7nT7JGZMbtM?t=6735)) only moments after 2nd stage separation the narrator says "And there it is; there's your critical call. James Webb not only has legs, but it has power..." They were waiting for a confirmation of "power positive" after solar panel deployment. So it could be a low gain signal to Malindi or perhaps local radio link to the 2nd stage.

Comment: You appear to be conflating the ground station that receives data from / sends data to a vehicle with the entity that commands and controls the vehicle. By way of analogy, suppose you have a WIFI-enabled IOT thermostat in your house, and you remotely command your thermostat to change settings. While some WIFI tower did relay the command to your thermostat, that WIFI tower is not in charge of your thermostat. You are, remotely.

Comment: @DavidHammen is the perceived conflation in my question, or in the comments. In the comments I'm just trying to piece together bits of information, so if conflation happened it's not so bad. If it's in the question itself, let me know and I can see about fixing it; we shouldn't have conflatory questions if we can help it.

Comment: @uhoh The conflation is in the links in your question, in the text of your question, and in your comments. You appear to be conflating communications passing through Malindi as Malindi being in control. Think of Malindi as the WIFI tower with which your IOT thermostat connects.

Comment: @DavidHammen oh then no I'm not trying to conflate them. I've added links that provide some general background information and reference them as evidence of some amount of research (e.g. this is what got me thinking about...), but if they contained any information about control they would be in an answer post, not in a question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag if you'd consider posting a short answer now that so much more information is available I can accept and we can call this "case closed".